# Express + CoffeeScript: Need to define classes in controller

Tags: javascript, express, coffeescript

I have such controller `api/meeting/meeting.controller.coffee`

```
class Talker
  constructor: (@name) ->
    talk: ->
      console.log "Talker name is" + @name

module.exports.meeting = (req, res, next) ->
  talker = new Talker 'Bob'
  talker.talk
```

This is how I import above file in my `index.coffee`

```
 controller = require './meeting.controller'
 router.post('/', controller.meeting );
```

This gets wired in `routes.js`:

```
`app.use('/meeting/',      require('./api/meeting'));`
```

Now wiring and routing works fine, but console.log from the class is never printed to my CLI. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It was an intendation and method call error. This is how it works:

```
class Talker
  constructor: (@name) ->
  talk: ->
    console.log "Talker name is" + @name

module.exports.meeting = (req, res, next) ->
  talker = new Talker 'Bob'
  talker.talk()
```